# Regex replace all commas between tags

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace with regex this string in java, this, because is a jtextArea which can contains many times this combination,

```
input
%fila%
Val1,val2,val3
%/fila%

output
<tr>
<th>val1</th>
<th>val2</th>
<th>val3</th>
</tr>
```

I try several times without luck

thanks for your help.

Comment: Input and output is totally different.

Comment: Does the pattern allow nesting?

Comment: Achintya Jha-> I need change the tag %fila% %/fila% for <tr> and </tr> this is not difficult, the problem is values wrap, val1 val2 and val3 with <th> </th>, dasblinkenlight-> is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very hard to do it with just one regular expression, but two expressions would do much better:

```
String test = "%fila%\nVal1,val2,val3\n%/fila%";

Pattern bracket = Pattern.compile("%([^%]+)%([^%]*)%/\\1%", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = bracket.matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    String middle = m.group(2);
    String tagged = "<tr>"+
        middle
        .replaceAll("[^,\n]+", "<th>$0</th>")
        .replaceAll(",","\n")
    +"</tr>";
    System.out.println(tagged);
}
```

The first expression finds the tagged area; the second (inside `replaceAll`) finds individual elements, and "frames" them with the `<th></th>` tags.

Unfortunately, this does not deal with nesting at all: if you nest multiple `%fila%`s inside each other, the above approach is going to fail. However, if you must allow for unlimited nesting of identical tags, regex will not be able to do it: in cases like that, you need to count the nesting level, yet the regex language is not powerful enough to do counting.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/FqbF4H).

Comment: Sir, you are my hero,I want to be like you when I grow up, thanks